# Get different days between array of date object

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, date, object

I got an array with date objects. And I need to display the different days between today from each object. Currently my Code looks like this, its just for one date "[0]", but it should also works for object arrays "sortedOpenBill". How could I handle this?

```js
const diffDaysinMS = new Date(sortedOpenBill[0]?.deadline).getTime() - new Date().getTime();
const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffDaysinMS / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

Comment: How should arrays be involved? The difference is an operation between two numbers, which two numbers are you interested in subtracting?

Comment: The deadline prop is an date object, so I need the diff days between deadline and today.

Comment: *How could I handle this?* do some basic logic/checks to define a var that you then pass `const deadline = Array.isArray(sortedOpenBill) && sortedOpenBill.length ? sortedOpenBill[0].deadline : sortedOpenBill.deadline` etc

Comment: If you have an array of *Date* objects and `sortedOpenBill[0]?.deadline` returns a *Date*, then the difference in milliseconds is given by `sortedOpenBill[0]?.deadline - Date.now()`, which is a lot less to type. Note also that where daylight saving is observed, there may be as few as 23 hours in a day and as many as 25 in another, once per year each.